# ggplot2 loess is creating a very odd weight legend, with blue square over the weighted dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the out graphic for my loess regression in R, I get this horrible looking key for the weights I assigned with blue bars over them. What can I do to make this look better/meaningful?

```
ggplot(mlsf, aes(value, total_points, weight=t1000_ownership, size=t1000_ownership))
 + +     geom_point()
 + +     geom_smooth(method='loess')
```

[image]

Comment: Just add `show.legend = FALSE` to `geom_smooth()`

Comment: @PoGibas Or `show.legend` maybe, I think `show_guide` has been deprecated in some later ggplot versions. Also, another option would be to move `size` aesthetic to `geom_point()`.

Comment: The problem is that `geom_smooth` is inheriting the `weight/size` aesthetics. I agree that those should probably be moved to  `geom_point()` or reset in `geom_smooth(aes(weight=NULL, size=NULL))` since they don't apply there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

When I tried moving size=t1000_ownership to geom_point, I get the error "Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint,  : 
  object 't1000_ownership' not found"

It seems like it doesn't know to pull from the dataframe?